# Add Text Into Textbox's in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, razor, excel, vb.net-2010, vba

Ok, so im trying to make this program and i need this: 
"Melternet Hello Melternet@gmail.com 5/7/2013" to be in different textbox's like this

"Textbox1 = Melternet"

"Textbox2 = Hello"

"Textbox3 = Melternet@gmail.com"

"Textbox4 = 5/7/2013"

So pretty much every space is a cut off line to add that text to a textbox and then it does the rest like the first one

How would i do something like that, thanks in advance.

Please Answer Back If Anyone Can Figure This Out Or Help Me, NEED THIS QUICK...

BTW: i'm using Visual Basic 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Without more info...something like:

```
    Dim data As String = "Melternet Hello Melternet@gmail.com 5/7/2013"
    Dim values() As String = data.Split(" ")
    If values.Length >= 4 Then
        TextBox1.Text = values(0)
        TextBox2.Text = values(1)
        TextBox3.Text = values(2)
        TextBox4.Text = values(3)
    End If
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote and/or click the checkmark so others know the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are simply splitting the entire input text string:  "Melternet Hello Melternet@gmail.com 5/7/2013" wherever a space occurs, yes(?)

If your string has a variable number of words, then fill up textboxes programmatically, like, e.g.:

```
Dim mystr as String
mystr = "hello world I want to paste this to multiple textboxes"

Dim Buff() as String
Buff = Split(mystr," ")
For i As Integer = 0 to UBound(Buff)
  Dim tb As New TextBox
  str = Buff(i)
  tb.Name = str
  tb.Text = str
  tb.Left = 50 
  tb.Top = 50 + 25 * i
  tb.Width = 50
  tb.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right
  Me.Controls.Add(tb)
Next
```

In the above fashion, no matter what the value of mystr, or how many words are in the string (mystr), you can write them all to new textboxes that are created/placed dynamically on Form1, i.e. "Me".